RANDARRAY with unique values
I have a list of unique words. I would like to populate some of them into a row range but every cell in the range would be filled in without duplicates.
=INDEX(A2:A120,UNIQUE(RANDARRAY(1,F1,1,ROWS(A2:A100),TRUE),TRUE))

so far I have this working formula, which provides the random unique values, however sometimes not all cells in the range filled in (because of the deleted duplicates). I saw solutions they use sequence to so solve this problem, but for mee it does not really work as it drops Calc! error.
=INDEX(A2:A120,UNIQUE(RANDARRAY(1,F1,1,ROWS(A2:A100),TRUE),TRUE), SEQUENCE(0,2))


So the list of words contain unique values? How many words are there, how many you want returned?

lets say I have a 100 words of list, there are already unique values. I would like to populate 20 of them into a row range. randomly and with unique values so the rand array not picking any of them multiple times. My formula almost populate the row what I want, but when it pick some cell from the list multiple times the unique formula will delete it, and it will be less then 20 values in the row.

I used this link to create the formula: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-randarray-function-generate-random-numbers/ and there is one section about using sequence to get unique and the exact amount of random cells. it works on numbers an column, I would like something similar to text and into 1 row.

In this example formula takes 10 random values of 15 values existing unique list.
=TOROW(INDEX(A2:A16,TAKE(SORTBY(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A16)),RANDARRAY(ROWS(A2:A16))),F1)))

Result:



Formula in C1:
=TOROW(UNIQUE(SORTBY(A1:A10,RANDARRAY(ROWS(A1:A10)))))


I edited the question as I did not explained well enough.

@TamasKosa, I still think you need to explain it to me a bit better. What's wrong with this solution?

In the list there are no duplicates (a1 column) in my case, My issue was that the randarray could pick up randomly the same values from the list and I've tried to solve it to use unique, but that one sometimes populated less values into my range.

Right, so again; what is wrong with the answer? @TamasKosa, besides the fact we no longer need UNIQUE() any longer

it takes all the values, not just a certain number of them, please see the question. In my F1 CELL, the row range.

So basically =TAKE(TOROW(SORTBY(A1:A10,RANDARRAY(ROWS(A1:A10)))),,F1) @TamasKosa

If I understood your problem correctly, you want to generate an array of non-repeating random numbers within a certain range, is that so?
=INDEX(SORTBY(SEQUENCE(C2 - B2 + 1, 1, B2, 1), RANDARRAY(C2 - B2 + 1)), SEQUENCE(A2, 1, 1, 1))



actually it is a list of  words in a column and I would like to generate some of them into a row range without duplication. I am trying it now

Just use XLOOKUP using this array to look up the list of your words.

I am not sure how can I do that

Another variant:
=TOROW(TAKE(SORTBY(A1:A100,RANDARRAY(100)),20))
Or more dynamic:
=LET(range, A1:A100,
     size,  20,
TOROW(TAKE(SORTBY(range,RANDARRAY(ROWS(range))),size)))

